# How to combine output of two HTML tables into single with some columns

Tags: powershell

I want to combine output of the `Get-VM` and `Measure-VM` cmdlets into single HTML table with some columns of `Get-VM` and `Measure-VM`.

I want the columns VMName, State, RAM, DISK.

`Get-VM` gives me VMName and State and `Measure-VM` gives me RAM and DISk.
So I want to combine these four columns into a single HTML table.

I have created code as below.

```
Get-VM –ComputerName $hostnm |
    Select-Object Name, State, Uptime,
        @{Name="RAM In GB";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.MemoryAssigned/1GB, 2)}} |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $a

Measure-VM –Name * -Computername $hostnm |
    Sort-Object VMName |
    Select-Object VMName,
        @{Name="RAM In GB";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.MaxRAM/1024, 2)}},
        @{Name="Disk Size in GB";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.TotalDisk/1024, 2)}} |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $a
```

So how do I combine this?

```
$vmhost = Get-Content C:\Users\Share1\Desktop\Scripts\VMHosts.txt
$file = "C:\Users\Share1\Desktop\Scripts\output.htm"

$report = "<html> <body>"
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "body {font-family: Tahoma; background-color:#fff;}"
$a = $a + "table {font-family: Tahoma;width: $($rptWidth)px;font-size: 12px;border-collapse:collapse;}"
$a = $a + "th {background-color: #cccc99;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-bottom: none;}"
$a = $a + "td {background-color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$op1 = @()
$op2 = @()
$myresult = @()

$output = foreach ($hostnm in $vmhost) {
    Enable-VMResourceMetering -Name $hostnm -ResourcePoolType @("Processor","VHD","Ethernet","Memory")

    echo "--------------------</br>"
    echo "<b>" $hostnm  "</b></br>"
    echo "--------------------</br>" 

    $op1 = Get-VM –ComputerName $hostnm |
           Select-Object Name, State, Uptime,
               @{Name="RAM In GB"; Expression={[Math]::Round($_.MemoryAssigned/1GB, 2)}} |
           ConvertTo-Html -Head $a 

    Get-VM –Name * -ComputerName $hostnm | Enable-VMResourceMetering
    $op2 = Measure-VM –Name * -ComputerName $hostnm |
           Sort-Object VMName |
           Select-Object VMName,
               @{Name="RAM In GB";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.MaxRAM/1024, 2)}},
               @{Name="Disk Size in GB";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.TotalDisk/1024, 2)}} |
           ConvertTo-Html -Head $a

    $myresult = $op1 + $op2
}

$report = $report + $output + $myresult + "</body></html>"
$report | Out-File $file
```

Actual result is I am getting two different tables of `Get-VM` and `Measure-VM`.

Expected result is only one table which has VM Name, State, RAM in GB, Disk in GB.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the data *before* building the HTML table.

```
$data = foreach ($hostnm in $vmhost) {
    $resources = @{}
    Measure-VM –Name * -ComputerName $hostnm | ForEach-Object {
        $resources[$_.VMName] = $_ | Select-Object MaxRAM, TotalDisk
    }

    Get-VM –ComputerName $hostnm |
        Select-Object Name, State,
            @{n='RAM in GB';e={[Math]::Round($resources[$_.Name].RAM/1024, 2)}},
            @{n='Disk in GB';e={[Math]::Round($resources[$_.Name].TotalDisk/1024, 2)}}
}
$table = $data | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a
```